# How can I insert a line break into a <Text> component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, text, react-native, newline

I want to insert a new line (like \r\n, <br />) in a Text component in React Native.

If I have:

```
<text>
<br />
Hi~<br />
this is a test message.<br />
</text>
```

Then React Native renders `Hi~ this is a test message.`

Is it possible render text to add a new line like so:

```
Hi~
this is a test message.
```

Comment: You can use `\n` where you want to break the line.

Comment: no \n will not work. i used. i would suggest use html tags for render and use css or simply <p> text </p>. you can use.

Answer (score 1080, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<Text>
Hi~{"\n"}
this is a test message.
</Text>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with string from variable so I could use:
`<Text>{content}</Text>` ?

Comment: \n is a line break

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up making a line break component for quick access

`var Br = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>
            {"\n"}{"\n"}
            </Text>
        )
    }
})`

Comment: This ended up line breaking my entire screen (all components on the same level). :S

Comment: Isn't there any tag like <br>? What if we want to give a line break b/w two tags?

Comment: is there anything to do linebreak based on text no count ?

Comment: What if the text is in a string variable? `<Text>{comments}</Text>` We cannot use the `{\n}` logic there. Then how?

Comment: If the text comes from a prop, make sure you pass it like this: `<Component text={"Line1\nLine2"} />` instead of  `<Component text="Line1\nLine2" />` (notice the added curly braces)

Comment: Using variable inside `<Text>{content}</Text>` with newline character will work normally. If that's not working it is due to `\\n` as newline character is escaped with the extra \. In that case use `<Text>{content.replace(/[^\]\\n/g, '\n')}</Text>`.

Comment: None of the suggestions on this page worked for me.
But I found something that worked elsewhere: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/newline-in-react-string-solved/68484
(basically inserting a symbol ('\n', for example) in the string and then in the rendering component splitting the string at each symbol and mapping the substrings)

Comment: This worked for me: {"\n"} inside tag Text

Comment: If you need to pass components inside the text, such as icons, you can do the following: <Component text={<>Some text then an icon <Ionicons  name="ios-information-circle"  /> then a line-break{"\n"}Then the end text.</>}. Note the <></>, which can also be replaced with other components that can go inside a <Text> component.

Answer (score 182):

You can also do:

```
<Text>{`
Hi~
this is a test message.
`}</Text>
```

Easier in my opinion, because you don't have to insert stuff within the string; just wrap it once and it keeps all your line-breaks.

Comment: this is cleanest solution so far, together with `white-space: pre-line;`

Comment: @Tomasz: I think there is no white-space or whiteSpace: -Stylesheet for <Text>-Tag in react-native - or am I wrong?

Comment: Template literals are clean and neat compare to accepted answer

Comment: I guess the white-space style is supposed to remove intendation spaces, right? If yes, I desperately need it, otherwise string literals get super ugly...

Comment: @Xerus You can just use a text post-processor to remove the indentation, as seen here: https://gist.github.com/Venryx/84cce3413b1f7ae75b3140dd128f944c

Comment: Great for bodies of text. You can't style individual words though.

Comment: this is cleanest solution so far, but it needs `white-space: pre-wrap;`, not `white-space: pre-line;`, in order to keep indentation correct.

Comment: agree, style of "white-space: pre-line" is the most clean solution, it works, and that's actually how html works.

Comment: I agree that this is the cleanest solution but it does not work on React Native which is what the question is asking. There is not a direct replacement for `white-space` on native and it doesn't work in all the cases.

Answer (score 79):

Use:

```
<Text>{`Hi,\nCurtis!`}</Text>
```

Result:

> Hi,
>
> Curtis!

Comment: This seems not to be working when the message is a string variable:

<Text>{message}</Text>

Comment: You can use function like this: splitLine = message => { ... } and RegExp in it, then <Text>{this.splitLine(message)}</Text>

Comment: If the passed text is empty the Text element will display "undefined".

Answer (score 65):

## Solution 1:

```
<Text>
  line 1{"\n"}
  line 2
</Text>
```

## Solution 2:

```
 <Text>{`
  line 1
  line 2
 `}</Text>
```

## Solution 3:

Here was my solution of handling multiple `<br/>` tags:

```js
<Text style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}>
    {"Hi<br/> this is a test message.".split("<br/>").join("\n")}
</Text>
```

## Solution 4:

use `maxWidth` for auto line break

```
<Text style={{ maxWidth:200}}>this is a test message. this is a test message</Text>
```

Comment: my up vote is for `white-space: pre-line` in solution 3 which allows you pass in a variable with `\n` style breaks and get them rendered

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me

```
<Text>{`Hi~\nthis is a test message.`}</Text>
```

(react-native 0.41.0)

Answer (score 23):

If at all you are displaying data from state variables, use this.

```
<Text>{this.state.user.bio.replace('<br/>', '\n')}</Text>
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use `{'\n'}` as line breaks. 
    
    Hi~ {'\n'} this is a test message.

Answer (score 13):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44845810/10480776 @Edison D'souza's answer was exactly what I was looking for. However, it was only replacing the first occurrence of the string. Here was my solution to handling multiple `<br/>` tags:

```js
<Typography style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}>
    {shortDescription.split("<br/>").join("\n")}
</Typography>
```

Sorry, I couldn't comment on his post due to the reputation score limitation.

Comment: This solution worked for me! Inside of the Typography I had this:
`{"${t('RateOptions.Details', { defaultValue: 'Rate info' })}".split('<br/>').join('\n')}`
Note the double quotes are supposed to be backticks

Answer (score 12):

EDIT :

if you use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (see within the `<Text>` element) , you can also just add the line breaks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class extends Component {

 (...)

 render(){
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{`
        1. line 1
        2. line 2
        3. line 3
      `}</Text>
    </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with styled-components and will work no matter if you use them or not.

Comment: I think the comment above is saying that `styled-components` isn't what is providing the line-break, so there's no reason to use or mention it as the solution. It's the template literal that's providing the line break. Also, suggesting to install a new package to solve a simple problem is not necessary.

Comment: This answer suggests adding `styled-components` but it's actually the template literal that provides the break, therefore `styled-components` does not participate in the solution at all. I should have made this more clear in my comment, sorry. Anyway it's hard to find a "constructive way to improve the answer" if it misses the point. If you're still looking for one though, then it would say something about removing `styled-components` from it leaving only template string literal, which are actually the solution (one of possible).

Comment: Thank you for the cooperation, what I meant was not that I don't know how to update the answer, but that instead of writing comments like that does not really help anyone, and if one thing stackoverflow teaches us is that cooperation makes wonders, therefore it's really appreciated if everybody replies in a constructive way. But honestly thanks for your contributions.

Comment: This suggestion helped to solve my case! Bravo

Answer (score 11):

Use `{"\n"}` where you want the line break

Answer (score 7):

I needed a one-line solution branching in a ternary operator to keep my code nicely indented.

```js
{foo ? `First line of text\nSecond line of text` : `Single line of text`}
```

Sublime syntax highlighting helps highlight the line-break character:

[image: Sublime syntax highlight]

Answer (score 6):

this is a nice question , you can do this in multiple ways
**First**

```
<View>
    <Text>
        Hi this is first line  {\n}  hi this is second line 
    </Text>
</View>
```

*which means you can use *{\n}* backslash n to break the line*

**Second**

```
<View>
     <Text>
         Hi this is first line
     </Text>
     <View>
         <Text>
             hi this is second line 
         </Text>
     </View>
</View>
```

*which means you can use another <*View*> component inside first <*View*> and wrap it around <*Text*> component*

Happy Coding

Answer (score 5):

You can try using like this

```
<text>{`${val}\n`}</text>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `` like this:

```
<Text>{`Hi~
this is a test message.`}</Text>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as follows:

{'Create\nYour Account'}

Comment: It worked form as well here <Header headerText={'Muhammad\n Tayyab\n Rana'} subHeadline="Web Developer and Designer"  />

Answer (score 3):

You can also just add it as a constant in your render method so its easy to reuse:

```
  render() {
    const br = `\n`;
     return (
        <Text>Capital Street{br}Cambridge{br}CB11 5XE{br}United Kingdom</Text>
     )  
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put `{'\n'}` within the Text tag

```
<Text>

   Hello {'\n'}

   World!

</Text>
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the cleanest and most flexible way would be using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

An advantage of using this is, if you want to display the content of string variable in the text body, it is cleaner and straight forward.

(Please note the usage of backtick characters)

```
const customMessage = 'This is a test message';
<Text>
{`
  Hi~
  ${customMessage}
`}
</Text>
```

Would result in

```
Hi~
This is a test message
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for React (not React Native) using TypeScript.

The same concept can be applied to React Native

```
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
  children: string;
  Wrapper?: any;
}

/**
 * Automatically break lines for text
 *
 * Avoids relying on <br /> for every line break
 *
 * @example
 * <Text>
 *   {`
 *     First line
 *
 *     Another line, which will respect line break
 *  `}
 * </Text>
 * @param props
 */
export const Text: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  const { children, Wrapper = 'div' } = props;

  return (
    <Wrapper style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }}>
      {children}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Text;
```

Usage:

```
<Text>
  {`
    This page uses server side rendering (SSR)

    Each page refresh (either SSR or CSR) queries the GraphQL API and displays products below:
  `}
</Text>
```

Displays:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Simple use backticks (ES 6 feature)

**SOLUTION 1**

```
const Message = 'This is a message';

<Text>
{`
  Hi~
  ${Message}
`}
</Text>
```

**SOLUTION 2** Add "\n" in Text

```
<Text>
Hi~{"\n"}
This is a message.
</Text>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite old but I came up with a solution for automatically breaking lines which allows you to pass in the text in the usual way (no trickery)

I created the following component

```
import React, {} from "react";
import {Text} from "react-native";

function MultiLineText({children,  ...otherProps}) {

const splits = children.split("\\n")
console.log(splits);
const items = []
for (let s of splits){
  items.push(s)
  items.push("\n")
}

  return (
    <Text {...otherProps}>{items}</Text>
  );
}


export default MultiLineText;
```

Then you can just use it like so..

```
<MultiLineText style={styles.text}>This is the first line\nThis is teh second line</MultiLineText>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two main solutions for this.

Method 1: Just add the `'\n'` like below

```
<Text>
   First Line {'\n'} Second Line.
</Text>
```

Method 2: Add the line break it in the string literals, like below.

```
 <Text>
   `First Line  
   Second Line`.
 </Text>
```

For more information, please refer the below tutorial.

https://sourcefreeze.com/how-to-insert-a-line-break-into-a-text-component-in-react-native/

Comment: Should be `{\`First line etc\`}`

Answer (score 3):

Y'all can try this if trying to use a variable inside an element.

```html
<Text>{newText}</Text>
```

```js
const newText= text.body.split("\n").map((item, key) => {
    return (
      <span key={key}>
        {item}
        <br />
      </span>
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

do this:

```js
<Text>

 { "Hi~ \n this is a test message." }

<Text/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting your data from a `state variable or props`, the Text component has a style prop with minWidth, maxWidth.

example

```
const {height,width} = Dimensions.get('screen');

const string = `This is the description coming from the state variable, It may long thank this` 

<Text style={{ maxWidth:width/2}}>{string}</Text>
```

This will display text 50% width of your screen

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n` in text and css `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Comment: I don’t see `whiteSpace` listed as a React Native [Text Style Prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props#texttransform). Note that this isn’t HTML.

Comment: for reference this works in react js. Others for some reason not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to insert `<br>` between text lines that are defined in an array:

```
import react, { Fragment } from 'react';

const lines = [
  'One line',
  'Another line',
];

const textContent =
  lines.reduce(items, line, index) => {
    if (index > 0) {
      items.push(<br key={'br-'+index}/>);
    }
    items.push(<Fragment key={'item-'+index}>{line}</Fragment>);
    return items;
  }, []);
```

Then the text can be used as variable:

```
<Text>{textContent}</Text>
```

If not available, `Fragment` can be defined this way:

```
const Fragment = (props) => props.children;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works on my environment. (react-native 0.63.4)

```js
const charChangeLine = `
`
// const charChangeLine = "\n" // or it is ok

const textWithChangeLine = "abc\ndef"

<Text>{textWithChangeLine.replace('¥n', charChangeLine)}</Text>
```

Result

```
abc
def
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for a solution where you want to have a new line for each string in an array you could do something like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View} from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      description: ['Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3'],
    };
  }

  render() {
    // Separate each string with a new line
    let description = this.state.description.join('\n\n');

    let descriptionElement = (
      <Text>{description}</Text>
    );

    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 50}}>
        {descriptionElement}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

See snack for a live example: https://snack.expo.io/@cmacdonnacha/react-native-new-break-line-example

Answer (score 0):

sometimes I write like this:

```jsx
<Text>
  You have {" "}
  {remaining}$ {" "}
  from{" "}
  {total}$
<Text>
```

(as it looks more clear for myself)

Answer (score 0):

Best way use list like UL or OL and do some styling like make list style none and you can use `<li> dhdhdhhd </li>`

Answer (score 0):

I also really liked solution #3 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69436906/1390874), but I was getting a **Console Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key 'whitespace'**

However, just passing my text inside symbols ``` {``} ``` with `\n` seems enough without any changes to the text style.
So for the original question the best answer IMHO would be:

```
{`Hi~\nthis is a test message.`}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why work so hard? it's 2020, create a component to handle this type of issues

```
    export class AppTextMultiLine extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
    const textArray = this.props.value.split('\n');
return (
        <View>
            {textArray.map((value) => {
               return <AppText>{value}</AppText>;
            })}
        </View>
    )
}}
```

Comment: Overhead, Just use template literals

Answer (score -1):

React won't like you putting HTML `<br />` in where it's expecting text, and `\n`s aren't always rendered unless in a `<pre>` tag.

Perhaps wrap each line-breaked string (paragraph) in a `<p>` tag like this:

```js
{text.split("\n").map((line, idx) => <p key={idx}>{line}</p>)}
```

Don't forget the `key` if you're iterating React components.

Answer (score -2):

```
<Text>
Hi~{"\n"}
this is a test message.
</Text>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: \n means new line.

Answer (score -2):

I used **p Tag** for new line. so here i pasted code .that will helpfu for anyone.

```
const new2DArr =  associativeArr.map((crntVal )=>{
          return <p > Id :  {crntVal.id} City Name : {crntVal.cityName} </p>;
     });
```

Answer (score -2):

**2021, this works for a REACT state Value *(you have to add empty divs, just like a return statement)***

`this.setState({form: (<> line 1 <br /> line 2 </>) })`

Comment: The question is concerned with React Native as opposed to plain React. In React Native we do not have`<br />` tags available.

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick !

```
<Text style={{styles.text}}>{`Hi~\nthis is a test message.`}</Text>
```

Answer (score -3):

Hey just put them like this it works for me !

> ```
>    <div>
>        <p style={{ fontWeight: "bold", whitespace: "pre-wrap" }}>
>          {" "}
>          Hello {"\n"}
>        </p>
>          {"\n"}
>        <p>I am here</p>
>    </div>
> ```

Answer (score -3):

An **empty View** does the trick

```xml
<Text> some text </Text>
<View />
<Text> another line </Text>
```