# Show newlines in React Native

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-native

I have an API that outputs some text extracted from MongoDB in JSON format. I want to show the text in my React Native, but I want to keep the newlines.

How should I store the newlines in my MongoDB so that I can print the text in my API and still show the text with newlines in React Native?

I'm wondering if I should use \n since I cannot use `<br>` since React Native is not able to render HTML.

Comment: `\n` indicates a newline, so yes.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32469570/2444365) may help you. Use {'\n'} instead of \n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert a line break into a text component in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469570/how-can-i-insert-a-line-break-into-a-text-component-in-react-native)

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this? I have the same problem