# How to insert line break in Reacti-Native

Tags: react-native

[How can I insert a line break into a text component in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469570/how-can-i-insert-a-line-break-into-a-text-component-in-react-native)

I checked here about my problem. 
But my case is a little bit different.
So it doesn't work with that way.
This is my container code and it gives props to ContactInfo.

```
  return data.map( 
    (contact, i) => { 
      return (<ContactInfo contact={contact} key={i} />); 
    } 
  );
```

This is child component. It recieves props as contact.

```
      <Text>{this.props.contact.name}</Text>
```

And finllay, it gives the result 'name'.
I expect

```
David
John
Wade
```

But it gives 'DavidJohnWade'.

I can't put `{"\n"}` and ` into  of child component since that is only one line.
How can i solve this?

Comment: Hi, you could try something this: <Text>{this.props.contact.name + "\n"}</Text>

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thx so much

Comment: Glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing a string, if you pass `{"\n"}` is just gonna see it as a string. try going the javascript way , use "\n" in your contact.name like `"David \n John \n Wade"`