# How to render in React Native a line break inside a string retrieved from a database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I can't get line breaks to work inside a string variable with React Native.
In my database I have documents with a field called name. Name is a string. Name can contains specific line breaks. Data is fetched in my React Native component and rendered in a FlatList.

I've tried various combinations of:

- \n
- {'\n'}

None of them work, the line break is render as text

```
\\ In database document
name: "Some\ntitle"
\\ or
name: "Some{'\n'}title"
```

```
\\ In React Native (simplified)
<FlatList
    renderItem={
        <Text>{item.name}<\Text>
    }
>
<\FlatList>
```

It is rendered as:
*Some\ntitle* or *Some{'\n'}title*

Instead of:
*Some
title*

**----------- SOLUTION -----------**

*// In database*
name: "Some\ntitle"

*// In React Native*
{item.name.replace('\n', '\n')}

*// Render*
Some
title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert a line break into a <Text> component in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469570/how-can-i-insert-a-line-break-into-a-text-component-in-react-native)

Comment: Nope, like mentionned in my question {'\n'} isn't working in this case

Comment: The question misses the part where you retrieve a string from a database. That's where the problem likely needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `\n` line feed appears literally means that it was escaped at some point, it is `\\n` in fact.

It can be `{item.name.replace('\\n', '\n')}`.

The actual problem is that it was escaped at all. This may affect other escape sequences and should be solved in the place where a string was escaped.

Comment: You did it! Who's the real player? Who's the real MVP ??

Comment: Yep, will do. Thanks for your time 

Comment: I answered this 30 minutes prior in a comment below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55410052/how-to-render-in-react-native-a-line-break-inside-a-string-retrieved-from-a-data/55410110#comment97542872_55410110

Comment: @lawrencealan I don't check other answers thoroughly so I was unaware of the comment. I don't consider SO a competition; I just provided the solution and the explanation. Any way, the comment should be a part of your answer because this is the real problem here.

Comment: It's obviously a competition, there's a scoring system and leaderboards :) – my answer answered his original question, but he expanded the scope over time, to which I expanded my answer and awaited his response, instead of responding to my comment, he accepted your answer, which is the same. All good, just worth noting.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{"\n"}` in place of `\n`:

```
Some{"\n"}text
```

or

```
<Text>{`Some\ntext`}</Text>
```

Comment: your approach is correct but how will you do this for a dynamic data? like in this question `Some Text` is coming from database. So it will be like `item.name`. how will you set `item.name` in a new line?

Comment: I've already tried this and it didn't work. The Text component is the renderItem of a FlatList component. name is a string stored in a mongodb collection. What Ankush Rishi said

Comment: Use a replace – `<Text>{item.name.replace(/\\n/g,'\n')}</Text>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
   {item.name.split("\n").map((i,key) => {
      return <Text key={key}>{i}</Text>;
   })}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, replace all the **\\n** to **\n**

```js
const t = d.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
<Text>{`{item.name}`}</Text>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's unpractical: when the items of a list are documents from a database  the content isn't hardcoded is the component, the line break has to be coded in the document then render in React Native

Comment: no, i thought of that but the notation inside the component don't change anything: <Component>{item.name}</Component> same result as <Component>{`{item.name}`}</Component>

Comment: Can you share your requirements more or share more code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution: we tested it and i seems working

```
  var str = item.name;
  var result = str.split("\n"); 
  return result.map((i, key) => <Text key={key}>{i + "\n"}</Text>);
```

Comment: I just updated the code, and it's working for me. please check

Comment: I suppose it should works for me too (@estus solution seems better though) but I can't manage to integrate it with my FlatList

Answer (score 0):

When I've stored document content in a database I've used `JSON.stringify()` to format the string before saving it and that will cause the string to include the raw `\n` in the string like what you have. To then render the string with the `\n` actually converted to new lines you should be able to simply pass that string into `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score -2):

Try styling the component with `style={{ whiteSpace: "pre" }}` to preserve the spaces

```
<Text style={{ whiteSpace: "pre" }}>{item.name}</Text>
```

Comment: whiteSpace isn't a React Native property