# React output does not preserve line breaks

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

Is there a way to preserve line breaks from user input. At the moment I am just getting the user input sending it to mongoDb and returning that text. However if my input is : 
"new
line",
my output would be "new line".
Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: Did you check this? Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469570/how-can-i-insert-a-line-break-into-a-text-component-in-react-native

Answer (score 4):

Use `css` [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for styling it.

```css
.foo {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a small addition to @FELIXMOSH's correct answer: also use `word-wrap` because `white-space` property can cause overflowing sometimes. And apply this css to the element that will host the mongodb data.

```
anyClass {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```