# how to make a new line for react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Refer to the  code below:

```
<item
     itemName={"laptop"}
     itemDescription={"- XXXX \n - PPPP"}    // how could I make a new line for this?
/>
```

\n is not working at this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I insert a line break into a <Text> component in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469570/how-can-i-insert-a-line-break-into-a-text-component-in-react-native)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 {text.split(“\n”).map(function(item) {
    return (
       {item}
       <br/>
    )
 })}
```

In your particular case it would look like this:

```
 itemDescription={<>XXXX <br /> - PPPP</>}
```

If your component takes nodes in that property, and not a string.

React doesn't use strings to create the HTMl, and HTML ignores line breaks, so you need to turn that string into JSX with line breaks, or paragraphs.