# Add newline characters with rich editing using Text inside TextInput

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have a Textarea component that handles Markdown headers:

```
type TextareaProps = {
    initValue: string;
    style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
    onChange?: (value: string) => void;
};

type OnChangeFun = NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputChangeEventData>;

const Textarea = ({initValue, style, onChange = () => {}}: TextareaProps) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(initValue);

  const changeHandler = ({nativeEvent: {text}}: OnChangeFun) => {
    setValue(text);
    onChange(text);
  };
  return (
    <TextInput
      style={[styles.textarea, style]}
      multiline
      onChange={changeHandler}>
      <Text>
        {value.split('\n').map((line, index) => {
          const style = line.match(/^#/) && styles.header;
          return (
              <Fragment key={`${index}-${line}`}>
                <Text style={style} >{ line }</Text>
                {"\n"}
              </Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </Text>
    </TextInput>
  );
};
```

The problem is that when I enter a character the cursor jumps two characters. If it's the last character in the line it jumps to the next line.

I've tried to add controlled selection:

```
const Textarea = ({initValue, style, onChange = () => {}}: TextareaProps) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(initValue);
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState<Selection>({
    start: 0,
    end: 0
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelection(({start, end}) => {
      if (start === end) {
        start += 1;
        end = start;
      }
      return { start, end };
    });
  }, [value]);
  const changeHandler = ({nativeEvent: {text}}: OnChangeFun) => {
    setValue(text);
    onChange(text);
  };
  const onSelection = ({ nativeEvent: { selection }}: OnSelectionFun) => {
    setSelection(selection);
  };
  return (
    <TextInput
      selection={selection}
      style={[styles.textarea, style]}
      multiline
      onSelectionChange={onSelection}
      onChange={changeHandler}>
      <Text>
        {value.split('\n').map((line, index) => {
          const style = line.match(/^#/) && styles.header;
          return (
            <Fragment key={`${index}-${line}`}>
              <Text style={style} >{ line }</Text>
              <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </Text>
    </TextInput>
  );
};
```

But this makes the whole content disappear when I type something or click inside the input.

Is there a way to add a new line after each line in the Rich Text editor and have the cursor in the right position?

Unfortunately, I can't create Snack with the code because this is totally broken in Snack, the output of the Textarea is `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your original code is caused by adding extra `\n` after the last line. Think about it: say you have `value` with 3 lines. When you render it inside `TextInput`, your next value will have 4 lines:

```js
line1\n
line2\n
line3\n
(empty line 4)
```

If you replace `{"\n"}` with conditional render, the problem is solved:

```js
const lines = value.split('\n');
// ...
return (
  <Fragment key={`${index}-${line}`}>
    <Text style={textStyle}>{line}</Text>
    {lines.length === index + 1 ? null : '\n'}
  </Fragment>
);
```

P. S. The cursor is moving by 1 extra character because apparently `React Native` tracks cursor position relative to the end of the input value; since you added 1 extra character to the end of the value, cursor remained fixed to `N` characters from the end, which caused it to visually jump by 1 extra character to the right with every update.

Comment: This works and explains the behavior, thanks.

Comment: P. S. I also figured out exactly why and how the cursor was jumping, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into all questions at: [How can I insert a line break into a  component in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32469570/387194) and found an [answer by Charlie Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72089880/387194) based his idea I came up with this code:

```
const Textarea = ({ initValue, style, onChange = () => {} }: TextareaProps) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(initValue);
  const changeHandler = ({ nativeEvent: { text } }: OnChangeFun) => {
    setValue(text);
    onChange(text);
  };
  return (
    <TextInput
      selection={selection}
      style={[styles.textarea, style]}
      multiline
      onSelectionChange={onSelection}
      onChange={changeHandler}>
      <Text>
        {value.split(/(\n)/).map((line, index) => {
          const key = `${index}-${line}`;
          if (line === '\n') {
            return <Text key={key}>{ line }</Text>;
          }
          const style = line.match(/^#/) && styles.header;
          return <Text key={key style={style}>{ line }</Text>;
        })}
      </Text>
    </TextInput>
  );
};
```

When newline is its own element own item in the array, the text input magically works.